# how do I create search bar which will update search on typing

Tags: android, eclipse, search

I created an application with the search on button click. How do I create search bar which will update search on typing letter? Something similar like in a google chrome. I was looking for an answer but I could not find it. Tnx a lot!

SearchableDictionary.java

```
package com.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;



public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ListView mListView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);



        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
            wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // handles a search query
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            showResults(query);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
     * @param query The search query
     */
    private void showResults(String query) {

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                                new String[] {query}, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            // There are no results
            mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
        } else {
            // Display the number of results
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                    count, new Object[] {count, query});
            mTextView.setText(countString);

            // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
            String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                           DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

            // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word
                                    };

            // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
            SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                          R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
            mListView.setAdapter(words);

            // Define the on-click listener for the list items
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                    Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                    String.valueOf(id));
                    wordIntent.setData(data);
                    startActivity(wordIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchable_dictionary, menu);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }


    }
```

DictionaryDatabase.java

```
package com.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class DictionaryDatabase {
    private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

    //The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
    public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
    public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

    public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
    }


    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
        map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
        return map;
    }


    public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);


    }


    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);


    }


    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                    " USING fts3 (" +
                    KEY_WORD + ", " +
                    KEY_DEFINITION + ");";

        DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadDictionary();
        }

        /**
         * Starts a thread to load the database table with words
         */
        private void loadDictionary() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadWords();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        private void loadWords() throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                    if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                    long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
        }


        public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);

            return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
    }

}
}
```

DictionaryProvider.java

```
package com.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;


public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
    String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

    public static String AUTHORITY = "com.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary.DictionaryProvider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

    // MIME types used for searching words or looking up a single definition
    public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                                  "/vnd.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary";
    public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                       "/vnd.bogdanskoric.searchdictionary";

    private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

    // UriMatcher stuff
    private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
    private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
    private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    /**
     * Builds up a UriMatcher for search suggestion and shortcut refresh queries.
     */
    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        // to get definitions...
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
        // to get suggestions...
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                        String sortOrder) {

        // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have and format the db query accordingly
        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                      "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
            case SEARCH_WORDS:
                if (selectionArgs == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                      "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
                }
                return search(selectionArgs[0]);
            case GET_WORD:
                return getWord(uri);
            case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
                return refreshShortcut(uri);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
      query = query.toLowerCase();
      String[] columns = new String[] {
          BaseColumns._ID,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
       /* SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                        (only if you want to refresh shortcuts) */
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

      return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor search(String query) {
      query = query.toLowerCase();
      String[] columns = new String[] {
          BaseColumns._ID,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

      return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
    }

    private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
      String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      String[] columns = new String[] {
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

      return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
    }

    private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {

      String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      String[] columns = new String[] {
          BaseColumns._ID,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
          DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

      return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_WORDS:
                return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
            case GET_WORD:
                return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
                return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/search_label"
android:hint ="@string/search_hint"

 android:searchSuggestAuthority="searchdictionary.DictionaryProvider"
 android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
 android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://searchdictionary.DictionaryProvider/dictionary"
 android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
 android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
 android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
 android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
>

</searchable>
```

raw/definition.txt

```
Adikcija - Podložnost nekoj štetnoj navici, najcešce, psihofiziološka zavisnost od droge ili alkohola (toksikomanija, alkoholizam).
Adolescencija - Period prelaska iz detinjstva u zrelo doba obeležen biološkim rastom, seksualnim..
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SearchView#setOnQueryTextListener` and perform filtering in `boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)` method of `OnQueryTextListener`. To perform filtering use `Filter`.